# Binding ObservableCollection to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reactiveui

I have next code on Control:

```cs
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
    vm => vm.RectangleCollection,
    v => ItemsControl.Items,
    value => value.ToString())
```

Code on WPF:

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="RectCanvas" Width="300" Height="300">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RectDataItem }">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RectDataItem" >
            <Rectangle Width="45" Height="45"></Rectangle> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button x:Name="RectButton" Width="50" Height="25"></Button>
</Canvas>
```

When I tried to convert To string for display collection in List or something else like a text i have next error:

> The type arguments for method `IReactiveBinding<TView,TOut> ReactiveUI.PropertyBindingMixins.OneWayBind<TViewModel,TView,TProp,TOut>(this TView, TViewModel?, Expression<Func<TViewModel,TProp>>, Expression<Func<TView,TOut>>, Func<TProp,TOut>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

My ObsCollection

```cs
public ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> RectangleCollection { get; set; }
    = new ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel>()
    {
       new RectangleViewModel() {Top = 50, Left=150, Height=25, Width=40},
       new RectangleViewModel() {Top = 75, Left=10, Height=45, Width=300},
    };
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ItemSource` on the `ItemControl`?

Comment: `v => ItemsControl.Items` should be `v => ItemsControl.ItemsSource`